# How to integrate Wordpress Post in Magento

Tags: wordpress

I have two websites :

1. [Wordpress](http://www.onestgrands.com)
2. [Magento](http://www.bed-wet.com)

I know the plugin of fishpig but I want to know how I can still have my WP blog and showing the posts into my Magento ( CMS for example ).
Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Assuming you have installed `FISHPIG` extension.
```

Goto

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wordpress/sidebar/widget
```

create a file and lets name it as `recents.phtml` and add the below code.

```
<?php
/**
* @category Fishpig
* @package Fishpig_Wordpress
* @license http://fishpig.co.uk/license.txt
* @author Ben Tideswell <help@fishpig.co.uk>
*/
?>
<?php $posts = $this->getPosts() ?>
<?php if (count($posts) > 0): ?>
<div>
<ul id="<?php echo $this->getListId() ?>">
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
<?php $post->setExcerptSize($this->getExcerptLength()) ?>
<li>
<?php if ($this->canDisplayExcerpt()): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($post->getPostTitle()) ?>">
<p><?php $content = $post->getPostExcerpt(); $content = strip_tags($content); echo substr($content, 0, 250); ?> ...</p>
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateList('<?php echo $this->getListId() ?>')</script>
<?php if ($this->canShowPager()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now create a CMS BLOCK say `Recent posts` and id `recent_posts` and add below code in content of that CMS Block.

```
{{block type=”wordpress/sidebar_widget_posts” name=”wordpress.widget.recent_posts” post_count=”1″ title=”Latest Blogs” excerpt=”on” excerpt_length=”250″ date=”off” comment_num=”off” template=”wordpress/sidebar/widget/recents.phtml”}}
```

Now call this block where ever you needed for example if you want to call it in `.xml` files call in this way

```
<block type="cms/block" name="recent_posts">
   <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>recent_posts</block_id></action>
</block>
```

To call it in content of CMS pages call in this way

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="recent_posts"}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, not working for me

Comment: Hmmm, not working for me either.

Answer (score 1):

> {{block type=”wordpress/sidebar_widget_posts”
>   name=”wordpress.widget.recent_posts” post_count=”1″ title=”Latest
>   Blogs” excerpt=”on” excerpt_length=”250″ date=”off” comment_num=”off”
>   template=”wordpress/sidebar/widget/recents.phtml”}}

to be replaced by

> {{block type="wordpress/sidebar_widget_posts"
>   name="wordpress.widget.recent_posts" post_count="1" title="Latest
>   Blogs" excerpt="on" excerpt_length="250" date="off" comment_num="off"
>   template="wordpress/sidebar/widget/recents.phtml"}}

Comment: What is the difference between replace and need to be replaced content from your answer?